# Is it fine to send data through push notifications (FCM)?

Tags: push-notification

I am planning to implement "promotional push notifications".
For example: "You are entitled to 20% discount" for loyal users and other such similar use cases.

Once the user clicks this push notification I want to show a screen that uses `dynamic data` to render everything like the title, percentageOff etc.

My open topic is where can I retrieve these data from: the notification itself or somewhere else.

My question is:
Is it ok to bundle into the push notification data information like

```
title
previousPrice
currentPrice
headline
benefit_1,2,...
```

so all the information required to render dynamically a screen in the mobile app ?

Or if you think or know that this is a wrong approach, can you please point me to the best and recommended approach for showing dynamic content after a user clicks a push notification and opens the app

Thanks